# Identifying suitable head (H) for hydro power estimation from 30m SRTM DEM data using focal statistic analysis

Tags: ogr2ogr

I am doing my project on identifying suitable sites for locating small-scale hydro power. I have all other necessary variables but I am confused about extracting Head (H) values in meters from SRTM 30m DEM using focal statistic analysis. Please someone help me. I have both 30m and 90m DEM and drainage network for my study area.

Comment: Head is a plumbing term indicating how far above/below the source water exists i.e. pressure real or potential, a pump is said to have 2 metres of head if it will pump water up a pipe for 2 metres but no more. In this case I believe it's potential pressure but that has nothing to do with OGR2OGR, what software are you using for this project? Do you have some extra hydrology tools?

Comment: Is this a dam project or a low-head hydro project (i.e. run of the river)? If it is the former, then the hydraulic head is going to be a function of the dam height (reservoir height really) and if it is a run of the river project (no dam) then it'll be a function of the slope of the river channel. That is, it would be a function of the drop in elevation over a certain distance.